# Parser grammar creation from sample data

Tags: ide, grammar, parser-generator

I have been looking around to see what's available as far as helping users create grammars. There are various IDE's, but... they appear to be text editors that work on the grammar file itself. I'm looking for something that works from a data-centric approach. So, let's say I have plenty of examples of the data I want to parse with the parser. So, I want to work through that sample data and define the grammar directly from it.

Is there any existing software that does something like that?

I'm going to try to be more clear...

A data-centric approach that I'm mentioning would be where the user loaded in a data sample. Then they would select pieces of it indicating they were fields, or select items and mark them as delimiters, or such.

As opposed to most of the IDE's I see out there are just text editors for writing in the grammar language itself.

Comment: I have always wondered about this but I think you have to extrapolate a grammar from your data set, but I am eager to see other people's answers.

Comment: Interesting question. See whether my answer is heading in the right direction... I can elaborate on any of the steps that I mention in getting a regular grammar/regex.

Comment: 1) In general, it's impossible to infer a unique grammar from the data. 2) Grammar description languages exist because people seriously researched this problem and came up with the best (from their perspective) solutions. So lack of "data-centric approach" is one indication that this idea is not viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any finite set of strings constitutes a regular language. It is trivial to write an NFA accepting such a language. From this, you can generate a DFA using the subset construction, and minimize it using the fact that DFAs need only one state for each equivalence class of the indistinguishability relation. So it's a completely algorithmic process... getting a regex and/or grammar is then similarly straightforward.

That being said, if you want to generate a grammar that generates the strings and, possibly, others... your problem seems ill-posed. For any finite set of strings, infinitely many grammars generate them and other strings... the infinitude of the number coming from the fact that you can generate any other strings, so long as you hit the target dataset. Your question is essentially, "given the beginning of a sequence a1, a2, ..., an, ..., say what the next n elements are." This is impossible to do, unless you just want *some* answer... in which case you could always start with the DFA and suggest ways to generalize this (i.e., only accept more strings).

Indeed, given e.g. a regular grammar, it's easy to introduce new strings... so maybe use the first answer as a starting place. Note, though, that the conversion from NFA to DFA can be wildly inefficient... asymptotically exponential.

Comment: The usual way this problem is posed is, "what's the minimal description that covers all the data?" leading to a much smaller set of grammars which do not dominate one another for some size or other complexity metric. OP also needs counter examples to get good grammars, otherwise the grammar G = CHAR* will be the only answer he'll get (being pretty minimal).  Fundamentally this is a machine learning problem. In general, I don't think he'll do very well unless his data is really regular, and in that case he won't need a tool.

Comment: Great info, but... I'm asking about software tools, not algorithms. I'm not suggesting something could do it automatically, rather just that is there a data-centric IDE instead of a grammar-centric IDE.

Comment: @taotree: Like I mention in the post, it seems like making a minimal DFA and corresponding regular grammar would be a good starting point... no idea whether there's anything actually doing this or not!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to limit this to FSAs, but rather grammars (whether context free or not).  I suggest looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_induction; there seem to be some discussions of algorithms (sorry, not software) there.